# UITableViewCell select doesn't working in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in Objective C and have a issue for using custom UITableViewCell.

I use touchesBegan in the my custom tableviewcell like following:

```
#import "UserListTableViewCell.h"

@implementation UserListTableViewCell

@synthesize userTableViewCellView, cellIndex;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
           ... .. ...
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
            ... ... ...
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
            ... ... ...
}
```

Then after that I can't use function  didSelectRowAtIndexPath{}.
How can I use TableView selection even though use touchesBegan method.

Please advance me if you can fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do some additional things with `touchesBegan` event? I think you can easily achieve by using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I mean doesn't work  didSelectRowAtIndexPath(). Do u have any advance?

Answer (score 0):

If didSelectRowAtIndexPath() isn't working properly after using touchesBegan you may want to check if you have [super touchesBegan] in your custom cell method. Like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
           [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

           ... .. ...
}

.....
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

This situation occurs because method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}
```

catches events, but doesn't send them further up the responder chain. As @Daniel mentioned above, if you add call to `super` like this:

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

events will be sent further to `- (void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.